# Запись массива в сессию

Tags: php, сессия

Как записать в сессию массив, следующего плана

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2041329
            [NAME] => Apple
            [PRICE] => 49900.00
            [QUANTITY] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2041331
            [NAME] => TV
            [PRICE] => 11800.00
            [QUANTITY] => 1
        )
```

Запись произвожу следующим видом:

```
 foreach($items as $k => $val){
                $_SESSION['items'] = $val;
            }
```

Но в сессии оказываются не все значения, подскажите как исправить сею ситуацию

Comment: ну, попробуй `$_SESSION['items'][] = $val;` чтоли

Comment: не, таким образом вообще ничего не попало

Comment: Маловероятно, но ладно. А почему просто не приравнять `$_SESSION['items'] = $items`?

Comment: @SLy_huh не "маловероятно", а единственный осмысленный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

У вас изначально не хватает знаний о том, как устроены массивы в PHP, и что из себя представляет переменная $_SESSION в нем. Как тут уже верно вам заметили, можно просто, безо всяких циклов, написать `$_SESSION['items'] = $items;`, и после получать сохраненные товары из корзины (или что у вас там за список товаров хранится), перебирая `$_SESSION['items']` как массив. Код будет примерно такой:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['ID'];
    echo $item['NAME'];
    /* ... */
}
```

если захотите вдруг обратиться напрямую, то это можно будет сделать так:

```
$_SESSION['items'][0]['ID'];
$_SESSION['items'][0]['NAME'];
/* ... */
$_SESSION['items'][1]['ID'];
$_SESSION['items'][1]['NAME'];
/* ... */
```

или так:

```
$arr = $_SESSION['items'];
$arr[0]['ID'];
$arr[0]['NAME'];
/* ... */
$arr[1]['ID'];
$arr[1]['NAME'];
/* ... */
```

Ссылка для обязательного изучения: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php
Но вообще советовал бы посмотреть/почитать какие-то обучающие материалы в стиле php for dummies, наверняка узнаете пару неожиданных вещей.

И да, массивы в PHP несколько отличаются от массивов во многих других языках программирования, если не хотите каждый раз наступать на грабли, которые описали здесь - лучше потратить день времени на совет в абзаце выше.

Answer (score 1):

Так может тоже работать.
`$_SESSION['items']=$items;`

Comment: вы...... это..........серьёзно?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский да, серьезно, а какая сторока Вас смутила Алексей?

Comment: первый `foreach` для `[1] => Array` и второй для `[ID] => 2041331.....`  каждого элемента. Это приблизительный код.

Comment: Меня смутило абсолютно всё. Начиная от того, что циклы можно вообще не использовать и заканчивая тем, что вы (то ли не знаете, то ли еще по какой-то причине) используете велосипед `foreach` со счетчиком `$i` вместо банально `for` ..... надеюсь вы его (foreach) не пихаете абсолютно везде и знаете про существование других видов цикла..... Но это велосипед костыльный еще тот, скажу я вам...))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский насколько я понял вопрос который был задан уважаемым @ChromeChrome, в первом блоке у него указан массив без завершающей скобки (массив не закрыт). То есть массив может иметь не только нулевую `0` и первую `1` итерацию (как показано в первом коде), но и иметь 100 и больше таких элементов и по этому цикл НУЖЕН. По поводу счетчика, я не считаю счетчик итерации в цикле `foreach` ошибкой. Но Ваше мнение учтено.

Comment: Цикл не нужен, так как достаточно `$_SESSION['items'] = $items`..... Но даже если и нужен цикл, то уж явно не ДВА

Comment: Согласен. Я просто в начале подумал что до цикл необходим... по какой либо причине...

Answer (score 1):

Это происходило потому что вы каждый элемент массива $items записывали в $_SESSION['items'], поэтому туда записовался последний элемент массива.

```
$_SESSION['items'][] = $val; //вот так правильно, только $_SESSION['items'] заранее нужно объявить пустым массивом
```

Проще записать их в сессию так:

```
$_SESSION['stored_items'] = $items;
```

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учетных записи, как их объединить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы абшиблись)

Comment: КТО, НУ КТО ЗДЕСЬ ПОДНИМАЕТ БЕССМЫСЛЕННЫЕ ОТВЕТЫ? Как и на английском сайте, здесь началась эпидемия "дать балл только за то что сподобился написать ответ"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в каком смысле? Пользователь с таким же именем но другим аккаунтом редактировал этот вопрос.

Comment: @Ипатьев редактирование не видел... думал  alexander barakin увидел в ответе "Это происходило потому" и решил что это второй случайны акк автора вопроса